# SharePoint WebPart Displays Twice - Help!

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I am a SharePoint novice who is responsible for maintaining several sites.

Recently, to organize a document library I opened it in Windows Explorer mode to drag and drop files.  I do this frequently.  I think I was moving too fast and inadvertently clicked something by mistake.  A dialog box popped up asking about hiding Webparts.  I think I clicked Yes.

I accidently hid the document library Webpart.  So I went in to Re-Add the WebPart to my page.  But now the Webpart appears twice on my page.  Only 1 Webpart is added, but two show up.  I removed the WebPart I added and closed the editor.  The document library still shows up even with no WebParts on the page!

This "phantom" library/webpart does not have a full menu bar or a View drop down and I am unable to add them because there is no WebPart associated with the library to go in and modify!  I need a full menu bar - otherwise I would leave it as-is.

I re-added the document library WebPart again and when I close out not only do I see the two webparts, but the Quick Launch shows two links with the same name!  I have to ask it to hide the link on the WebPart I have access to so only one link will appear.

Does anyone know what going on?

Answer (score 5):

If you add **`?contents=1`** to the end of your page URL then SharePoint will display a 'maintenance style' list of all web parts on the page (including those closed). From here you can delete any that are causing a problem.

Once they're all cleaned up, add back the web part you need and it should behave normally.

Comment: +1 Make sure to DELETE it, not CLOSE it, otherwise it will still remain on the page (invisible, but still)

Comment: Cheers for this answer! I was looking for it in several threads, but none actually gave a useful answer. This one works like a charm